# useInfiniteQuery is duplicating the data every time and just increasing the data count by 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-query

I am building a scroll component with help of useInfiniteQuery in react-query. The data is also getting fetched, but the data is just incremented by one, and that doesn't effect how much I increase the variable by. I am putting some screenshot for better understanding.

[image: Screen shot 1 of data]

[image: Screen shot 2 of Data]

Whenever I map the data it shows me 9 duplicate data and 1 fresh data.

**InfiniteQueryHook.jsx**

```
import axios from "axios";

import { useInfiniteQuery } from "react-query";

const getComments = async (page) => {
  console.log(page);
  return axios.get(`https://dummyjson.com/comments?skip=${page}&limit=10`);
};

export const useGetComments = () => {
  return useInfiniteQuery(
    "Comments",
    ({ pageParam = 1 }) => getComments(pageParam),
    {
      getNextPageParam: (lastpage, allPages) => {
        
        if (lastpage.data.comments.length < 10 || lastpage.data.comments === []) {
            return undefined
        }
        return allPages.length + 1
      },
      keepPreviousData: true
    }
  );
};
```

**InfiniteScroll.jsx**

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import Aos from "aos";

import "aos/dist/aos.css";
import { useGetComments } from "../../hooks/infiniteQueryHooks/infiniteQueryHooks";

const InfiniteScrollComponent = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [pageNo, setPageNo] = useState(2);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);
  const { data, isSuccess, hasNextPage, fetchNextPage, isFetchingNextPage } =
    useGetComments();
  console.log("--------------");
  console.log(data);
  console.log("--------------");
  console.log(hasNextPage);

  useEffect(() => {
    Aos.init();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let fetching = false;
    const onScroll = async (event) => {
      const { scrollHeight, scrollTop, clientHeight } =
        event.target.scrollingElement;
      if (!fetching && scrollHeight - scrollTop <= clientHeight * 1.5) {
        fetching = true;
        if (hasNextPage) {
          await fetchNextPage();
        }
        fetching = false;
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  const fetchData = () => {
    axios
      .get(`https://dummyjson.com/comments?skip=${pageNo * 10}`)
      .then((result) => {
        // console.log(result.data.comments);
        console.log(result);
        if (result.data.comments.length < 10 || result.data.comments === []) {
          setHasMore(false);
        }
        setPageNo(pageNo + 1);
        setItems([...items, ...result.data.comments]);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  if (!data) {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(data)}
      {data.pages.map((dataes, index) => {
        console.log(dataes);
        return dataes.data.comments.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
              key={index}
              data-aos="fade-right"
              data-aos-offset="25"
              data-aos-easing="ease-in-sine"
              data-aos-duration="600"
            >
              <h6>{item.postId}</h6>
              <p>{item.body}</p>
            </div>
          );
        });
        
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default InfiniteScrollComponent;
```